# Swift - Overwrite navigation bar

Tags: swift, controller, navigation, uibarbuttonitem, overwrite

When it comes to opening a new View Controller i didnt want it to be presented modally so i pushed it in navigation controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newView")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The View with the identifier "newView" is presented correctly and there is also a navigation bar with a back-button provided, which also works properly.

But how to customize this existing navigation bar, add new bar button items etc.. ?

any suggestions?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: thanks for downvoting and no answer :(

Comment: *any suggestions?* [yes](https://www.google.de/search?q=uinavigationbar+custom&client=safari&hl=de-de&biw=375&bih=559&prmd=imsvn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdt-KAw4nLAhUlSJoKHag4BFIQ_AUIBCgA&dpr=2)

Comment: Btw: down vote for pasting unrelated working code but showing no attempt to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: i already viewed these guides, but there is no option given, how to setup a new navigation bar.. which i would like to create via storyboard.. you understand my point?

Comment: I don't get, what you a struggling with. Create a subclass, set it in the storyboard. And I doubt you looked carefully enough.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "Create a subclass, set it in the storyboard"? the view i am pushing on the stack already got a subclass and it is set via storyboard..but i cant customize a navigation bar created by "pushViewController" in this subclass. Thats what i am struggling with. you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track by subclassing from UIViewController the `newView`. I doubt you could customize the navigation bar on the storyboard. 
You have to do it in code.

In `viewDidLoad()` of newView, you can have these:

```
var helloButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hello", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "sayHello:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = helloButton
```

Implement the `sayHello` method:

```
func sayHello(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```